# Как правильно пользоваться Picasso?

Tags: android

В андроид есть либа Picasso.
У меня 2 вопроса
1) Как увеличить размер кеша и указать чтобы кеш хранил на sd карте.
Просто она сохраняет максимум 4-10 картинок в кеше. Каждый раз новые качает.

2) У меня 10 окон и в каждом я пишу, правильно ли я делаю. Или нужно Picasso использовать 1 раз и чтобы она была статичной?
Picasso.with().....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно заюзать подобную конструкцию

```
Picasso picasso =  new Picasso.Builder(this).downloader(new OkHttpDownloader(getCacheDir(), 250000000)).build();
Picasso.setSingletonInstance(picasso);
```

Вместо `getCacheDir()` укажите путь на SD карточку. `250000000` - размер кэша (250 МБ)

> Или нужно Picasso использовать 1 раз и чтобы она была статичной?

Это и так синглтон

Comment: Тоесть мне после вашего кода всегда использовать объект picasso?

Или Класс Picasso?

Comment: Класс, вы же зададите новый инстант в синглтоне, после этого объект юзать нету нужды. Чтобы лучше понять это перечитайте про синглтоны